# How to stablish a WebRTC connection without cam or mic?

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

I'm using peerjs to implement a video conference application, the thing is that I want clients to connect even if they don't have mic or camera, when I get the user
media I check if they have available devices, when they don't have any or if they block the devices I try to fallback to an empty MediaStream, but when I try to connect two peers the behavior of the connection only works as intended when the initiator has a conventional stream product of calling getUserMedia, if the initiator has an empty MediaStream things just don't work at all.

Comment: What do you expect to do with a video conference connection without an audio or video source?

Comment: some users might want to listen, but if they don't have media devices they could use the text chat, or just listen.

Answer (score 5):

the `OfferToReceiveAudio` and `OfferToReceiveVideo` options of webrtc should allow you to create a recv only peerconnection .

here a reference in peerjs code:
https://github.com/peers/peerjs/blob/cfc37c7988d8ef3d2c1d7b6123562dd2af59defc/test/peer.ts#L63

For recent browser and with webrtc native api you have to add `Transceiver` with direction set to recvonly:

```js
 peerConnection.addTransceiver('audio', {
          direction: 'recvonly',
        });
```

I don't know how to do that with peerJs

Comment: I can connect peer to peer but i don't hear sound audio to my partner